# Calling External Dynamic Links from VBulletin > Need Links to Open in Base Target iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm currently using the following script to call the 5 latest active threads from a VBulletin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://[VBulletin]/external.php?forumids=1&type=js">
</script> 
<script language="" type="text/javascript">
<!--
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
document.writeln("<a href=\"http://[VBulletin]/showthread.php?t=" +threads[x].threadid+"\">"+threads[x].title+"</a> (Posted By: "+threads[x].poster+")<br />");
}
</script>
```

I'd like to have the populated forum links to open in an iFrame of the parent page (the above code is in a secondary iFrame of said page).  In standard HTML, it would be: `<a href="link" base target="pageframe">`, but I'm unsure of how to do the same function in JS within the above code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming all of this is on the same domain, and that your target iframe had an id like `<iframe id="openlinkshere">`
You could add a handler on your links like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://[VBulletin]/external.php?forumids=1&type=js">
</script> 
<script language="" type="text/javascript">
<!--
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
document.writeln("<a onclick=\"top.document.getElementById('openlinkshere').location.href = this.href; return false;\" href=\"http://[VBulletin]/showthread.php?t=" +threads[x].threadid+"\">"+threads[x].title+"</a> (Posted By: "+threads[x].poster+")<br />");
}
</script>
```

This would open the link on your target iframe

```
top.document.getElementById('openlinkshere').location.href = this.href;
```

This stops event propagation so your "list" iframe stays where it is.

`return false;`

Comment: I couldn't seem to get that to work - syntax error reported, and I am clueless when it comes to JS...  was able to get the following to work: `{
document.writeln("<a base target='pageframe' href=\"http://[VBulletin]/showthread.php?t=" +threads[x].threadid+"\">"+threads[x].title+"</a> (Posted By: "+threads[x].poster+")<br />");
}`

Comment: I forgot to escape the quotes for the onclick attribute. I wanted to give you an idea not the whole code. Nevertheless, this should work.